# Set Yii Model relation to other field

Tags: php, yii, relationship

I have relation:

```
'tbl2' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tbl2', 'id_tbl2')
```

It referrer `tbl1.id_tbl2` to `tbl2.id` table. But now I need to make it referrer to `id1` in `tbl2`.

`tbl1` is **MyISAM** and `tbl2` is **InnoDB**

Want to add relation for that field in `tbl1` and again generate model in gii but in **phpMyAdmin** row **Relation view** disappear, as I understood it works only for InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this :

```
'tbl2' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tbl2', array('id_tbl2'=>'id1'))
```

And if you want to use gii, you should use InnoDB.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/database.arr

Comment: I know it's something easy. Thanks!